# Python, in decorator with argument, how are arguments passed in

Tags: python, functional-programming, scope, arguments, decorator

```
def repeat(num_times):
    def decorator_repeat(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)    
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):   
            for _ in range(num_times):
                func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator_repeat

@repeat(num_times=2)   
def say_whee(name):     
    print(f"Hello {name}")

say_whee('Alex')
# Hello Alex
# Hello Alex
```

say_whee function object is passed in decorator_repeat, however, to me, it seems no parameter is passed into wrapper. Inside wrapper, it has access to func because it is accessed through outer scope. But how does func(*args, **kwargs) get access to say_whee's param, namely 'Alex'? It seems that decorator takes func, then func's params just magically seep through to wrapper as well as func inside wrapper. How is this implemented behind the scenes?

Answer (score 2):

`repeat` is not the decorator; it's a decorator *factory*. The function it returns (`decorator_repeat`) is a *closure* over `num_times`, so `num_times` is available as a (nonlocal) variable to the closure *it* returns (`wrapper`). Without decorator syntax, you would write

```
def say_whee(name):     
    print(f"Hello {name}")

# decorator = repeat(num_times=2)
# say_whee = decorator(way_whee)
say_whee = repeat(num_times=2)(say_whee)
```

which might make it a little easier to see that the thing that `repeat` returns is what is applied to the original `say_whee` function.

Even with decorator syntax, you can assign the result of `repeat` to a temporary variable if that makes more sense to you:

```
repeat_twice = repeat(num_times=2)

@repeat_twice   
def say_whee(name):     
    print(f"Hello {name}")
```

---

If you are wondering how closures are implemented (at least in CPython), each function has an attribute that lets you see the values retained from the defining scope for use by the function. Specifically,

```
>>> repeat_twice = repeat(num_times=2)
>>> repeat_twice.__closure__[0].cell_contents
2
```

`__closure__` is a tuple of `cell` objects, each of which has a `cell_contents` attribute whose value is the value assigned to the original variable.

Answer (score 0):

both repeat and `decorator_repeat` are called at the line where the decorator is applied to the function, they return the wrapper function `wrapper`.

now wrapper is also defined at the moment when the decorator is applied, so it will look like this

```py
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):   
            for _ in range(num_times):
                say_whee(*args, **kwargs)
```

this function is a simple wrapper that takes arguments and passes them to `say_whee`,

now the decorator takes your variable `say_whee` and reassigns it to this new function in the global scope.

```py
say_whee = wrapper
```

if this was all it does then wrapper would end up calling itself, but it doesn't because it doesn't call `say_whee` , it calls `func` which is the old value of `say_whee`

```py
func = say_whee  # this line executes inside `decorator_repeat` local scope
say_whee = wrapper  # this line is then executed globally.
```

because functions take their variables from the local scope to which they were defined before checking the global scope, `func` references `func` from the local scope of `decorator_repeat`, which is the old value of `say_whee`, which is why it is able to keep its value even though `say_whee` no longer points to your old `say_whee` that you defined, but instead points to the newly created `wrapper` function.

same thing happens to `num_times` which takes its value from the local scope of `repeat`.